# Headers/footers and paging not exported with mPDF and PHPExcel?

Tags: php, phpexcel, mpdf

I use mPDF with PHPExcel and it seems like headers and footers are not exported from my excel content. Is there a way around that?

If not, can I re-create/add the headers and footers right before the PDF is created?

If not, is there a way to just add page numbers to the pdf?

Thanks!

Edit // More code. See the Header/Footer part:

```
PHPExcel_Settings::setZipClass(PHPExcel_Settings::PCLZIP);

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader("Excel2007");
$objReader->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("excel.xlsx");

$rendererName = PHPExcel_Settings::PDF_RENDERER_MPDF;
$rendererLibraryPath = dirname(__FILE__) . '/mpdf';

$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

// Header and Footer
$title = "Title";
$sub_title = "Subtitle";
$sub_title = "Title";
$date_exported = date('Y-m-d H:i');

$objWorksheet
    ->getHeaderFooter()->setOddHeader('&L&14'.$title."\n&11".$sub_title."&R&10Exported with PHP\n" . $date_exported);
$objWorksheet
    ->getHeaderFooter()->setEvenHeader('&L&14'.$title."\n&11".$sub_title."&R&10Exported with PHP\n" . $date_exported);
$objWorksheet
    ->getHeaderFooter()->setOddFooter("&RPage &P of &N");
$objWorksheet
    ->getHeaderFooter()->setEvenFooter("&RPage &P of &N");

$excelRow = 1;
$excelCol = 0;
$columns = Array('Title 1','Title 2','Title 3');
foreach($columns as $column_title)
{
    $objWorksheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($excelCol, $excelRow, $column_title);
    $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($excelCol,$excelRow)->getStyle()->applyFromArray(
                array(
                    'font' => array(
                        'bold' => true,
                    ),
                    'alignment' => array(
                        'horizontal' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_LEFT,
                    ),
                    'borders' => array(
                        'top' => array(
                            'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN,
                            'color' => array('rgb' => '000000')
                        ),
                        'bottom' => array(
                            'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN,
                            'color' => array('rgb' => '000000')
                        )
                    ),
                    'fill' => array(
                        'type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
                        'color' => array('rgb' => 'd9d9d9')
                    )
                )
           );
    $objWorksheet->getColumnDimensionByColumn($excelCol)->setAutoSize(true);
    $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($excelCol,$excelRow)->getStyle()->getAlignment()->setWrapText(false);
    $excelCol++;
}

$objWorksheet->getPageSetup()->setOrientation(PHPExcel_Worksheet_PageSetup::ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
$objWorksheet->getPageSetup()->setPaperSize(PHPExcel_Worksheet_PageSetup::PAPERSIZE_LETTER);
$objWorksheet->getPageSetup()->setFitToPage(true);
$objWorksheet->getPageSetup()->setFitToWidth(1);
$objWorksheet->getPageSetup()->setFitToHeight(0);
$objWorksheet->getPageMargins()->setTop(0.5);
$objWorksheet->getPageMargins()->setRight(0.7);
$objWorksheet->getPageMargins()->setBottom(0.5);
$objWorksheet->getPageMargins()->setLeft(0.75);

if (!PHPExcel_Settings::setPdfRenderer(
        $rendererName,
        $rendererLibraryPath
    )) {
    die(
        'NOTICE: Please set the $rendererName and $rendererLibraryPath values' .
        '<br />' .
        'at the top of this script as appropriate for your directory structure'
    );
}

header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="pdf.pdf"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'PDF');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
```

Comment: It would help if you included a sample of the PHP you using to generate the PDF, as well as what HTML you are passing to mPDF.

Comment: @JakeJackson More code in place! Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I found this for page numbers, but how do I incorporate that into my code? https://mpdf.github.io/paging/page-numbering.html

Comment: I'd strongly recommend upgrading to PHPSpreadsheet as PHPExcel is considered a dead project by its authors https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel. The PHPSpreadsheet PDF code allows you to directly interact with the mPDF class, so you can add extra features like page numbers.

Comment: @JakeJackson Thanks, I looked into it but I'm already pretty invested in the phpExcel and I'm new to the whole composer world and couldn't figure out how to  get it installed. Is there a version that doesn't require autoloaders and other stuff? Thanks!

Comment: @JakeJackson Do you know if there is any way to install it without composer?

Comment: You aren't going to get any support for software that is considered dead by the original authors. I'd strongly reconsider the upgrade to PHPSpreadsheet.

Comment: I’m talking about PHPSpreadsheet. Any way I can install it without composer? Thanks!

Comment: You will want to create a new question asking that.

Comment: I found this site https://php-download.com/package/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet

Comment: @SeaBass you got any solution ?

Comment: @Debugger unfortunately not :(

Comment: @SeaBass how you solved this issue ?

Comment: @Debugger just told you I didn’t

Comment: @SeaBass I got the solution

Comment: @Debugger Did you post it?